# facing issue while starting hive server and hive web interface

Tags: hadoop, hive

((1))

I'm getting the below error while starting thrift server:

```
hive --service hiveserver

Starting Hive Thrift Server
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.
```

when I ran netstat port 10000 was already in use..

```
$ netstat -nl | grep 10000
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN
```

How do I resolve this?

((2))

While starting hive web interface getting below error

```
hive --service hwi

$ hive --service  hwi
13/01/01 22:05:36 INFO hwi.HWIServer: HWI is starting up
13/01/01 22:05:37 INFO mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
13/01/01 22:05:37 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
13/01/01 22:05:37 INFO mortbay.log: Extract /opt/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.9.0.jar to /tmp/Jetty_127_0_0_1_3606_hive.hwi.0.9.0.jar__hwi__.6ogsv5/webapp
13/01/01 22:05:37 WARN mortbay.log: failed SocketConnector@127.0.0.1:3606: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
13/01/01 22:05:37 WARN mortbay.log: failed Jetty20SShims$Server@21e554: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try `netstat -nl | grep 9999` to check which process use the port where `9999` is the default hwi port.

Comment: change the default address and try running it again.

Answer (score 3):

Your port address seems to be used by some other program, you may follow below mentioned steps :-

((1)) Start hive server using another port address

```
    hive --service hiveserver -p 10001 &
```

((2))

a] create hive-site.xml file if not present in $HIVE_HOME/conf folder
   b] put following lines in it

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
   <configuration>
   <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.listen.port</name>
    <value>9998</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>lib/hive-hwi-0.10.0.war</value>
    <description>This sets the path to the HWI war file, relative to ${HIVE_HOME}. </description>
   </property>
   </configuration>
```

c] start hive web interface

```
    hive --service hwi
```

d] browse localhost:9998/hwi/

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem here is the solution I got

1)set port numer

```
           export HIVE_PORT=10000
```

2)   Check which services is listening

```
     sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

3)if there is process relevant to port 10000 kill it

```
     kill -9 pid
```

4) Start hive server

```
         $HIVE_HOME/bin --service hiveserver
```

If it not work go to step 2 and start server again

Answer (score 0):

Stop Hive;

Add the following properties in hive-site.xml

1) hive.hwi.listen.host = host

2) hive.hwi.listen.port = 9999

3) hive.hwi.war.file = /lib/hive-common-0.12.0.2.0.6.1-102.jar {This sets the path to the HWI war file, relative to $HIVE_HOME}

Start Hive again

Start HWI on Hive server with the command

nohup hive --service hwi &

Now, you can access HWI as host:9999/hwi

Answer (score 0):

If this kind of issue arises run

```
$ bin/metatool -listFSRoot
```

If it runs with out error then try to run the `metastore` and then check the hive can fetch the record from a table or not.

Answer (score 0):

normally this issue arises .
Either you are changing the hostname  so that what ever the user u have created in the metastore it still refering to the old metastore hostname.

Case -1  either metastore is not up  which throws  the above  error so run the bin/metatool -listFSRoot if it ran without error then u r able to connect hive safly.

but still issue is not resolved case -2

Case-2  what ever the  table created in the hive still points to the old hiveuser which was pointing to the old host name so u cant featch the record from the hive table .

Solution :- revert the host name in all the file with old host name  and then run the hadoop and hive stack one after other.

Apart from this if any one has other solution please share.This I resolved in my production box.